# При наведении на иконку, она менялась на слово

Tags: javascript, html, css, icon

Есть иконка при наведении на которую она пропадала и её заменяло слово "Элита". Можно ли такое сделать? Спасибо.

Иконка:

```
<i class="far fa-gem" style="font-size: 12px;"></i>
```

Comment: можно, конечно. где ваши попытки решить задачу?

Comment: или хотя бы предпочитаемый способ типа css или чистый js или jquery

Answer (score 5):

Тут JS не нужен, достаточно CSS. У вас иконка через Font Awesome, а значит она задана через before content. Можно при наведении подменять это свойство на нужный вам текст.

`<i class="far fa-gem icon" style="font-size: 12px;" data-title="Элита"></i>`
CSS

```
.icon:hover::before {
  content: attr(data-title);
}
```

В место attr(data-title) можете просто опдставить свой текст в кавычках, но я предпочитаю не вставлять контент внутри CSS, поэтому через функцию data беру его из атрибута data-title нужного тега.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeText(theTag,textto) {
        theTag.innerHTML=textto;
    }
```

```html
<span style="cursor: pointer;" onmouseover="changeText(this,'текст, на который заменяем')" onmouseout="changeText(this,'изначальный текст')">изначальный текст</span>
```